# Testing on device but I can't save the file to music on device?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I dev a app and test it on my device.

```html
var webClient = new WebClient ();
   webClient.DownloadDataCompleted+= (object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e) => 
   {
    var bytes=e.Result;
    string documentsPath=System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic);
    string localFilename=Intent.GetStringExtra("title").Replace("_","");
    string localPath=Path.Combine(documentsPath,localFilename);
    File.WriteAllBytes(localPath,bytes);
   };
```

I always get null at documentsPath. How to save the file to device(.mp3)

Comment: Have you added the read/write permissions to the manifest? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  `

Comment: So I use mymusic or commonmusic in SpecialFolder